# Method to return file rather than writing to file

Tags: c#

I have the following method to create csv files - it creates a file in a specified directory.

How do I amend this method to return the created file rather than writing to disk?

```
public void CreateCSV(DataTable dt,string aTitle)
{

  string filePath = String.Concat(@"P:\folderX\",aTitle,@"-",this.guid,@".csv");
  string delimiter = ",";

  //size of the datatable
  int NumRows = dt.Rows.Count;
  int NumCols = dt.Columns.Count;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  List<string> CsvRow = new List<string>();

  //try to deal with the headers first
  foreach(DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
  {
    CsvRow.Add(c.ColumnName.ToString());
  }
  sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter,CsvRow));

  //now add the bulk of the data
  foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
  {
    CsvRow.Clear();

    //go through each column adding to a list of strings
    foreach(DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
      CsvRow.Add(r[c.ColumnName].ToString());
    }

    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter,CsvRow));
  }



  File.WriteAllText(filePath,sb.ToString());

}
```

Comment: Dont write it to file, return the string

Comment: Just by returning `sb.ToString()`. Or what do you mean by _return file_ ?

Comment: What do you mean on "return the created file rather than writing to disk"? File is a piece of data stored on disk. If you don't want to create file, you can return string, array of bytes or MemoryStream depending from what you want to do with your data.

Comment: Streams. When in doubt, always use streams. If you want to do anything else to that file (upload, encrypt, encode, compress, etc.) it's always easier if you have a stream.

Comment: depends on what you want to do next: if this is a web application, you will want a stream which you can send as part of a `Response`. btw. if this is really supposed to be a CSV format, this code is missing the necessary escaping for the delimiter (if commas were to occur in the data)